# Intellisense suddenly stops working or shows lot of inconsistency in VS2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, intellisense, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I am using VS2008 for my VC++ coding.
I observe lots of inconsistency (Sometimes intellisense works fine & sometimes it suddenly stops working) wrt intellisense.

And sometimes intellisense stops all of a sudden. And manily for vector in VC++ i see it doesnt work at all.

I am really bugged of VS2008 (I feel VS2005 was simply superb compared to VS2008 user interface). VS 2008 is too bugging.

Can anyone kindly help me in getting rid of this error & make intellisense working fine.

Answer (score 4):

You can delete the .ncb file to force it to rebuild the intellisense you have to close the solution if you want to do this, reopen the solution after deleting, or you can purchase [Visual AssistX](http://www.wholetomato.com/) which is what I use at home and work.

The other thing is that they have rewritten intellisense as of VS2010 so it uses SQL to store the DB and improve the performance.

I know this is not much comfort to you but intellisense is notoriously annoying.

Comment: In order for the intellisense .ncb to ger recreated after I delete the old one, is it necessary for the VC++ solution to build SUCCESSFULLY or will .ncb get fully recreated even with a build failure. PLz let me know this before i delete old ncb. Thanks.

Comment: Such notorious behaviour could never be seen in VS2005. VS2005 is simply superb.

Comment: Intellisense is built when you add new classes, methods and definitions, when you delete the file (must do this with visual @codeLover studio closed) and reopen the solution you will see in the status bar at the bottom building intellisense (X of X) where it is parsing the files, you don't need to compile but if you want intellisense to be working you have to wait for it to complete